# Should I change my Google Analytics Tracking Code when the content of my website changes?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have changed the content in my website. Now should I change the Google analytics tracking code?

What changes in website affect the Google analytics tracking code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from scratch, change your code.  If you want to keep your old stats and build on them, then leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the tracking code is to track visitors to your site, not content. You have no reason to change your tracking code.

Answer (score 1):

No changes in the site content ever affect the tracking code. So long as every page has the tracking code, all pages are tracked, regardless of whether new pages are added or if existing pages are deleted or if the content is changed.

Even if you deleted 100% of all the content and used all new content, you could still use the existing GA code. Your GA reports will show both the old traffic and the new.

If for some reason you completely changed the focus of your website (say it was about cats, now its about food), and if it makes no sense to show old traffic in any report, then you can update your GA code by incrementing the ID number by one (UA-xxxxxxxx-1 to UA-xxxxxxxx-2) and creating a new GA property with that code.

Then your reports will show the new properties traffic starting on the date you created the new code, but your old property and all the old traffic will still be retained in another GA view.